# What kind of Forum platform is this?

Tags: web-apps, forum

I was wondering if anybody could tell me what kind of forum platform this is? I find a lot of websites using it although nobody seems to be answering this question at Quora.

https://community.airtable.com/

Comment: Meta discussion: [Is software identification on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/818/60)

Comment: Please see http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/818/is-software-identification-on-topic, you can make your question on-topic by describing the features you see and want, including a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site is¹ using [**Discourse**](http://www.discourse.org/) ([Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_%28software%29)), which is free/libre/open source software.

The developers tried "to reimagine what a modern Internet discussion platform should be today". It could be described as a mix between mailing lists, discussion forums, and chat rooms. See their [FAQ](https://www.discourse.org/faq/) and the [features](https://www.discourse.org/about/).

---

¹ The mentioned site contains a reference to the software in the footer, but it’s only visible if JavaScript is disabled:

> Powered by [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/), best viewed with JavaScript enabled

Comment: I appreciate it!